# Is there an easy way to watch Blu-ray in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: blu-ray

I have tried to get it to work in the past with no success.

[image]
makemkv

Comment: Make sure you have bluray hardware, too!

Answer (score 14):

Commercial DVDs and Blu-ray discs are DRM protected.

DVD discs work well but Blu-rays are a bit difficult.

The free VLC media player can play DVDs on Linux, but it requires a special library known as libdvdcss. This library effectively breaks the CSS encryption on DVDs, allowing you to watch them.

Press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

The terminal opens

Now in the terminal type:

```
sudo su
apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

Follow on screen instructions to complete the installations

Then type

```
apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

Close terminal.

You can now open VLC and attempt to open a Blu-ray disc. Click the “Media” menu, select “Open Disc,” and select “Blu-ray.” Leave the “No disc menus” option checked.

[image]

If you see error follow the next steps:

Type in terminal

```
add-apt-repository ppa:heyarje/makemkv-beta
apt-get update
apt-get install makemkv-bin makemkv-oss
```

Open the MakeMKV application from your menu, select your Blu-ray disc drive, and click the “Stream” icon on the toolbar. You’ll be given a local address.

[image]

Open VLC, click the “Media” menu, click “Open Network Stream,” and provide that address. It will look similar to the following address:

```
http://localhost:51000/stream/title0.ts
```

The main movie is usually either “title0” or “title1”–choose the one that looks larger in MakeMKV.

[image]

MakeMKV will decode the Blu-ray video and stream it to VLC. VLC plays the video, but MakeMKV is doing the main workload in background.

**Option 2:**

Use MKV to rip blue ray disk to hard drive with encryption removed.

Select mkv from dash menu and start it

Insert your disk.

[image]

Disk analysis will take place automatically, wait for the process to be completed.

Click on the first icon of top menu saying open files and select your disk from Nautilus file manager

Select your movie title from here

[image]

Click on MakeMKV and select the rip location on your hard drive

[image]

It will take some time to finish. After that one or more MKV files will be produced.

Now play them with VLC media player.

Comment: The question is about Blu-Ray not ordinary DVDs. Most Blu-Ray has DRM which is not easy to deal with.

Comment: Dang. Well I was just hoping it may having gotten easier since my last attempt.

Comment: @RoBByWeBeR hope it works now

Comment: in makemkv i insert the blu-ray disc, it reads, and then says: No disc inserted. I tried this with 2 different blu-ray discs.

Comment: @Deuce I have edited my answer try the second method now