# Playing Blu-Rays

Tags: video, vlc, blu-ray

I'm beginning to wonder if it's even possible to play commercial Blu-Ray discs under Ubuntu.

I have `~/.config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg`, half a dozen BD-related packages and looked at many guides, some of which were less than a year old. I'm on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 x64, by the way.

**VLC output:**

```
Blu-ray error:
Your system BD+ decoding library does not work. Missing configuration?
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.
```

**MakeMKV output:**

```
MakeMKV v1.10.6 linux(x64-release) started
Using direct disc access mode
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Error 'Scsi error - ILLEGAL REQUEST:COPY PROTECTION KEY EXCHANGE FAILURE - KEY NOT ESTABLISHED' occurred while issuing SCSI command AD010..080002400 to device 'SG:dev_11:0'
Can't read AACS VID from disc - most likely current AACS host certificate is revoked by your drive
Highest AACS version is v14 , MKB saved as /home/james/.MakeMKV/MKB_v14_BORAT_F1.tgz
The volume key is unknown for this disc - video can't be decrypted
Failed to open disc
```

**VLC output after linking `libmmbd` to `libaacs` and `libbdplus`:**

```
Blu-ray error:
Blu-ray Disc is corrupted.
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.
```

I have tried *The Simpsons Movie* and *Borat! Cultural Learnings of America for Make Benefit Glorious Nation of Kazakhstan* - nothing else as my other Blu-Rays are newer so less likely to work. All of them are Region B or region-free.

**March 2018 Update:**

Still no real luck but I've got MakeMKV working. However, this only really works for ripping Blu-Rays which isn't exactly what I want to do. Handbrake partially works, with audio and corrupted video - again, that's ripping, not playing.

Comment: Even playing regular old DVDs is mess... I don't think you're going to be playing Blu-Rays any time soon, unfortunately. Sometimes you still need Windows for stuff like MS Office, advanced photo/video editing and playback of DRM-protected content :(

Comment: Kodi works fine.

Comment: @AndroidDev DVDs on Ubuntu have always been very simple for me. Simply install and configure `libdvd-pkg` then use VLC to play. For some reason, that results in copyright warnings and trailers being skipped, but that's usually what I want anyway. However, I'm quickly realising that Blu-Rays are a different beast, especially since Blu-Ray players have the ability to update their firmware. I may try using a Windows virtual machine to play Blu-Rays later this week as it does tend to have more support for this sort of stuff.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks for the Kodi suggestion. I've installed it and it can get the track list but I'm getting "playback failed" when attempting to play any of them.  I'll play around with it a little - this is a step in the right direction, at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to watch Blu-ray in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811071/is-there-an-easy-way-to-watch-blu-ray-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I've voted to close your question as a duplicate. If you try the duplicate and it doesn't solve your problem let me know and I'll retract my close vote. Thank you.

Comment: [Part 1] @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've now installed `browser-plugin-vlc` and will see if that magically makes Blu-Rays works in VLC. It doesn't sound like it will help but the linked answer includes it so I'll roll with it anyway. Will be able to try once I've finished ripping a Blu-Ray to watch.

Comment: [Part 2] @WinEunuuchs2Unix The streaming option in MakeMKV works if I increase VLC's cache time, but then I can't pause or fast-forward without it freezing up so that's not an ideal option and gets very tedious for special features. I've probably already seen every answer you could link to unless there have been any new helpful ones in the past few months.

Comment: @spacerGIF I don't even use my 3-D blu-ray player attached to my TV let alone the blu-ray players for PCs. I'll retract my close vote and hope someone can help.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Just tried it and no such luck. `No valid processing key found in AACS config file.` or `Your system BD+ decoding library does not work. Missing configuration?` depending on the age of the disc. It's worth noting that I managed to get two Blu-Ray players for Windows partially working - one degraded and watermarked the picture and the other stuttered. Windows on VirtualBox won't recognise my drive. Anyway, thanks for noticing my question.